# Using SQLite with Template 10

Tags: sqlite, mvvm, template10

Does anyone know of an example of SQLite with Template 10 using Template 10's built in **MVVM** support?

I am struggling to understand how to separate the code into `Models/Views/ViewModels/Services.`

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: depends are your understanding of MVVM to begin using it in T10 know the framework first with incremental steps towards your end goal.  SQLite woks very well and works well with EnittyFramwork Core or choice of wrapper for SQLite.  I uses services to access websites, models are my entities, viewmodels sorta of expose the models, depends on your complexity in the end.

Comment: I also use EF Core 1.1.0